# FFMPEG convert and codec

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a CENTOS and i installed ffmpeg with: `yum install ffmpeg` command

I'm trying to converting a video with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "C:\home\app\cedoc\convert\TREINO_PSC_ACD_PR_02_09_14_IMAGEM_GOROTO_PRESO.MXF" -crf 18.0 -vcodec libx264 -filter:v scale=1920:1080 -preset veryslow -acodec libvo_aacenc -ar 48000 -b:a 192k -coder 1 -flags +loop -cmp chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -me_method hex -subq 6 -me_range 16 -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -b_strategy 1 -threads 0 "C:\Users\lanhellas\Documents\TREINO_PSC_ACD_PR_02_09_14_IMAGEM_GOROTO_PRESO.mp4"
```

But i got the following:

```
Unknown encoder 'libvo_aacenc'
```

This is my ffmpeg configuration:

```
ffmpeg version 2.6.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic' --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```

Comment: look at ur -acodec value . its not in your build of ffmpeg. find a diff audio codec among those in ur build ( u can list all codecs with cli command ) . try another value that comes near matching the output u get from  just 'ffmpeg -i $your-audio-input

Comment: I'm Very newbie about ffmpeg, is there anyway to enable this Codec ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libvo_aacenc produced low quality audio and was eventually [removed from FFmpeg](https://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=e07e88cd82f78644ddcb10d7d3e0dd624fffe274).

Available AAC encoders are:

- `aac` The native FFmpeg AAC encoder. Works fine for most users, but your version is way too old to include the major improvements to this encoder. An easy method to update is to [download an already compiled `ffmpeg`](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/), then optionally move it to `/usr/local/bin`.
- `libfdk_aac` Highest quality AAC encoder supported by FFmpeg but requires that you [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos).

See [FFmpeg Wiki: AAC](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC).

---

Your command has a few additional problems:

- The command looks like it is for Windows (`C:\`), but your `ffmpeg` info looks like it is on Linux, so you may have to fix the paths to your files.
- You have many options that you should not be using. The `-preset` deals with all of the extra stuff, so once you update `ffmpeg` your command can simply be something like:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i input.mxf -c:v libx264 -vf scale=1920:1080 -preset veryslow -c:a aac -b:a 192k output.mp4
  ```

Comment: Perfect answer i updated my ffmpeg and your command works, but i have a problem: The convert is VERY VERY slow, about 30 minutes to convert a 1GB file. There is anyway to fast it ?

Comment: @RonaldoLanhellas Use a faster `-preset`. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/H.264) for more info. I need to see your command and the console output to make any additional suggestions. You can use a pastebin site and provide the link here in a comment.